# How to make responsive events fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

i have a fullcalendar but don't show responsive the events on month, day or week on mobile devices:

[image]

this is my javascript:

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //aspectRatio: 0.7,
    navLinks :true,
    monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
    editable:false,
    firstDay:1,
    handleWindowResize:true,
    customButtons: {
        add_event: {
            text: '+ Agregar Evento',
            click: function() {
              $("#modalEvento").modal({
                show:true,
                backdrop:'static',
                keyboard:false
              });
            }
        }
    },
    slotDuration:'00:15:00',
    buttonText: {
      today:'Hoy',
      month:'Mes',
      week:'Semana',
      day:'Dia'
    },
    header:{
     left:'prev,next today, add_event',
     center:'title',
     right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
    },
    events: 'incld/load.php',
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true,
    eventBorderColor: 'red',
    eventBackgroundColor:'white',
    //eventHeight:'150',
    displayEventEnd:true, 
    selectLongPressDelay:1000, //mobile
    eventLongPressDelay:1000,
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {  
      html = "<div class='col-lg-12 col-xs-12'>"
      html +="<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='detalleEvento("+event.id+");' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' role='button'>Detalle</a>";
      html += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      //html+= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='editarEvento("+event.id+");'><span class='badge badge-warning'>Editar</span></a>";
      //html += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      html += "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='eliminarEvento("+event.id+");' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' >Eliminar</a>";
      html+= "</div>"


      element.find('.fc-content').after(html)
    },
    select: function(start, end, allDay){
      if (moment().diff(start, 'days') > 0) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        return false;
      }else{
        document.getElementById('formEvento').reset();
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        date = start._d;

        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        $("#modalEvento #fecha_inicio").val(today);
        $("#modalEvento #fecha_fin").val(today);
        $("#modalEvento").modal('show');
      }
    },
  });//end fullcalendar
```

now, to add buttons action use the **eventAfterRender** with this code:

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {  
  html = "<div class='col-lg-12 col-xs-12'>"
  html +="<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='detalleEvento("+event.id+");' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' role='button'>Detalle</a>";
  html += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  html += "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='eliminarEvento("+event.id+");' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' >Eliminar</a>";
  html+= "</div>"

  element.find('.fc-content').after(html)
},
```

maybe the problem is when i add this buttons for actions "Detalle" and "Eliminar" buttons, maybe some one suggest please, thanks..!!

Comment: Where is your CSS? You should tag this as CSS as well, doesnt really have anything to do with JS. The "Detalle" button will never fit what that font size so you should start by using smaller font on mobile.

Comment: i  don't have a custom css only use bootstrap...

Comment: Well then how do you hope to change anything? Bootstrap is a CSS framework not a replacement for ALL css.

Comment: fullCalendar is unfortunately based on a fixed grid layout system and as such most of the views are not really suited to mobile. Try using something like the list view, or a single day view, when your page detects a small screen size.